# what does $f''$ suggests about the graph of $f$?

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

[image]

As I read the question, I only understand $g'(0)=0$ means $g$ has a local minimum or maximum there, so the solution must be A,B or E.

That's all. Can you help me figure out what $g''$ suggests?

Thank you

Comment: The only thing you "understood" is wrong. There are functions with derivative 0 at a point but not a local min/max there. Consider $f(x) = x^3$ for example.

Comment: pardon my lack of knowledge, then how do you solve this problem?

Comment: the signe of $g^{"}$ give you if the graphe of $g$ is concave or convex in an interval

Comment: from what $g''$ gave, it seems like A or B would be the solution, right? what to do next?

Comment: In (B), $g$ is convex on $(0,0.4)$, so $g''$ is positive on that interval, violating the last condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- $g'(0) = 0$ eliminates (C), since it's slope of tangent at $x=0$ is positive.
- $g''(-1) > 0$ indicates the local convexity at $x=-1$, so (E) is eliminated.
- $g''(x) < 0$ on $x \in (0,2)$ indicates the concavity there, so (B) and (D) are eliminated.

Observe that (A) verifies the above three criteria, so (A) is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

$g''(x)>0$ tells you that it is strictly convex at x. Here is why:

Let $x<y$

$0<\int\limits_x^yf(t)dt=f'(y)-f'(x)$

so $(f'(y)-f'(x))(y-x)>0$ which is an alternative definition of convex

Comment: from what g′′ gave, it seems like A or B would be the solution, right? what to do next?

Comment: Why not D? and the third condition tells you about concavity between 0 and 2